# Connected Components are either equal to each other or have nothing in common. Any Hint is appreciated

Tags: general-topology

The connected component definifiton

$(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ topological space. $(A, \mathcal{T}_A)$ subspace topology. Let $x\in X$

> $ C_x:= \bigcup_{, A\subset X,  x \in A, (A, \mathcal{T_A}) connected} A$.

I need to show that if there are two connected components, then they either equal or intersection is empty.

I tried prove directly from the definition. But couldn't go anywhere.

Comment: Show that the union of connected sets that have a common point is connected.

Comment: @user40276 just show connected components are connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are equal then nothing to prove.

Suppose they are not equal and have a point in common.Then $C_x,C_y$ being connected $C_x\cup C_y$ is connected.By your construction of $C_x$ and $C_y$ ;

$C_x\cup C_y\subseteq C_x $ and $C_x\cup C_y\subseteq C_y$ i.e $C_x=C_y$